# How can my web app/website support both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2? (Asset bundling)

Tags: javascript, css, http, css-sprites

According to [this link](https://www.kaizensearch.co.uk/blog/seo/7-steps-check-list-switch-http2/) and [this link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/getting-ready-for-http2/) when preparing for HTTP/2 there is little point in using HTTP/1.1 best practices like concatenating CSS/JS files and using image sprites. Many smaller assets are likely better for HTTP/2 due to it's non-blocking nature.

But what if I want to be able to serve users the same experience regardless of which HTTP versions their browsers support. **How can I bundle my assets in a way which will serve both types of guest a rich user experience?**

Comment: my personal *opinion* is to make the experience as painful as possible for numpties that still use old browsers - in other words, IE <= 10 and opera mini - I'm in the process of making my sites inoperable for IE11 as well, by using `=>` everywhere it's appropriate